# Error in specifying connection weights of neural network in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I'm using MATLAB R2014a and I want to create below Neural Network:

[image: Connection weights of dashed lines are -1 and other solid lines weight's are 1]

Using below code:

```
net=network;
net.numInputs=2;
net.numLayers=3;
net.inputConnect=[1 1;0 0;0 0];
net.layerConnect=[0 0 0;1 0 0;0 1 0];
net.layers{1}.size=2;
net.layers{2}.size=4;
net.layers{3}.size=2;
net.outputConnect=[0 0 1];
net.layers{:}.transferFcn = 'hardlim';
net.trainFcn = 'trainscg';
net.inputs{1}.size=4;
net.inputs{2}.size=4;
```

I receive this network:

[image]

Now when I want to specify input weights with this code:

```
net.inputWeights=[1 1;0 0; 0 0];
```

Or this one:

```
net.inputWeights{1,1}=1;
```

I've got this error:

```
Error using network/subsasgn>network_subsasgn (line 267)
You must assign to subobject properties individually[.][3]

Error in network/subsasgn (line 13)
net = network_subsasgn(net,subscripts,v,netname);
```

And with `net.IW=[1 1;0 0; 0 0];`, error will be this:

```
Error using network/subsasgn>network_subsasgn (line 553)
net.IW must be a 3-by-2 cell array.

Error in network/subsasgn (line 13)
net = network_subsasgn(net,subscripts,v,netname);
```

Also I tried `net=configure(net,x,t)` and `net = train(net,x,t)` functions when for example: `x=[1 2 3 4]; t=[1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5];` but I receive this error for `configure` function:

```
Error using network/configure (line 111)
The numbers of input signals and networks inputs do not match.
```

and this one for `train` :

```
Error using network/train (line 320)
Number of inputs does not match net.numInputs.
```

So, how can I complete this custom Neural Network for details like connection weights?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've solved the problem with below code:

When I had used the code which I explained in my question, there was no ability to change the weights of connection in manual mode. But with this code (code I've showed in my answer), I can change the weights and other settings without any error. `feedforwardnet` is proper function in MATLAB.

```
net=feedforwardnet([2,4,2]);
net.numInputs=2;
net.inputConnect=[1 1;0 0;0 0;0 0];
net.layerConnect=[0 0 0 0;1 0 0 0;0 1 0 0;0 0 1 0];
net.inputs{1}.size=1;
net.inputs{2}.size=1;
net.IW{1,1}=[1;0];
net.IW{1,2}=[0;1];
net.LW{2,1}=[-1 1;1 -1;-1 -1;1 1];
net.LW{3,2}=[1 1 0 0;0 0 1 1];
view(net);
```